# How does stdout store data? - C

Tags: c, memory, monitor

How does the monitor store the data displayed on it? Is it stored in memory and if so how can I access it? The reason I am asking is because I am programming a text editor, in which I use an array to store the data being manipulated. I was wondering if I could access the memory containing the data displayed on the screen rather than using my own array. It seems redundant to reserve memory for the same data twice. But I just don't know how the monitor stores the data displayed on it or if it even stores it at all.

Comment: A text editor ain't a kernel. You don't need to (and should not) try to access the [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) directly. Also, stdout is already a level of indirection between the framebuffer and a userspace process, you're confusing it with the actual hardware register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make very few assumptions about where `stdout` goes. It might go to a terminal, where it will end up in a buffer somewhere. Or it might be piped to another process. Or it might to to `/dev/null`. Or to a line printer, etc. And even in the cases where it does end up in memory somewhere, that buffer will have a limited size, and hence not necessarily hold the whole file. And you probably won't have permission to access that memory anyway. So while this could in theory work in certain circumstances, it is definitely not the right way to go.

You will probably not want to use stdout for your text editor at all, but something like `ncurses`, which lets you place text where you want in the terminal, and update it at will. The actual contents of the file is probably best managed through your own internal buffers, the way you are already doing it, though you might consider `mmap` too.

Answer (score 1):

Stdout is the output stream of a program. The environment you run the program from determines where this stream points to. You are probably running the program from either a console terminal or from some IDE.

Console terminals by default store the output internally themselves, unless instructed to redirect the output to a file or another program's input.

You can't rely on third party to store any output info for you to later query without any agreement. You'll want to hold enough data inside your program to generate views you want. And yes, as above stated, ncurses and such libraries make console app building a bit easier.